# Export current view of DetailsList (Fluent UI) to csv

Tags: fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I would like to know how to export the current view of detailsList(filtered, sorted data) to csv or any other format. Maybe someone already had an experience with this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a wrapper over fluentUI data grid (DetailsList) which supports export functionality with many more capabilities: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluentui-editable-grid

```
<EditableGrid
    id={1}
    columns={columns}
    items={items}
    enableExport={true}
    height={'70vh'}
    width={'140vh'}
    position={'relative'}
    layoutMode={DetailsListLayoutMode.justified}
    selectionMode={SelectionMode.multiple}
    enableRowEdit={true}
    enableRowEditCancel={true}
    enableBulkEdit={true}
    enableColumnEdit={true}
    enableSave={true} />
```